# css: changed background color of div A when div B is hover

Tags: html, css

I've got 2 div tags: Div A and Div B. 
If Div B is hovered, then I need to changed background color of Div A.
Can this be achieved with pure css only? I have already tried "~" "+" ">"

Comment: `if B is hovered change color of B.` .b:hover{...}

Comment: question..lol..correct it plz

Comment: see to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: Put your HTML, we aren't wizards or witches to view trascendental codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Adjacent sibling selector +`

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

.a:hover + .b {
   background-color: red;
}
```

according to your previous words, this should be it. but let me know if your structure is more complex than this

Comment: In your code the bgcolor of B will changed what I'm asking is what if the reverse, when I focus/hover on B the bg color of A will changed.Thankz

Answer (score 0):

```
B:hover 
{
    background: #code;
}
```

Comment: if you can read the title then read back..op wants to change the background color of div a on hover of b..and use background-color rather then background when you know op wants to change color..

Comment: But the description is different.

Comment: if you can read other answers or comment then you can see what everyone got.it was typo..sorry m not being rude but you should not mark these as answer..it can lead to wrong way..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to hover `A` and change CSS of `B`

You may want to try this

```css
.A,
.B{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.A:hover+.B{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
```

Comment: The OP already tried `+`. So do you think OP is looking for this?

Comment: In your code the bgcolor of B will changed what I'm asking is what is the reverse, when I focus/hover on B the bg color of A will changed.Thankz